# Excel VBA code adding blank rows

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and I have written the below code that is supposed to compare dates in two columns, and take which ever date is greater and display it on a Worksheet called PPDCI. If there is no dates, or dates are equal then it will display that record on another worksheet called "Error" and "REVIEW PPD DATA".

The program seems to work fine for the first two IF conditions for variables PPD_1_Date and PPD_2_Date that output data to the PPDCI worksheet, however the results on the Error tab are not what I am expecting. It seems to be including blank rows (rows that I believe are on the PPDCI tab with data), rows that only contain the cell with "REVIEW PPD DATA" (ID, Name information missing), and rows that just have data in columns A - C (sourced from the "Data" worksheets columns F - H).

I tried changing the code (commented out below) to include a condition for if the two date fields are empty then GoTo EmptyRange, just prior to iterating the Next i. This producted a runtime error though, even though it works on several other functions in my module

```
Function PPDdate()

Dim PPD_1_Date As Date
Dim PPD_2_Date As Date
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

j = Worksheets("PPDCI").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
k = Worksheets("Error").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
For i = 2 To lstrow

PPD_1_Date = Worksheets("Data").Range("AW" & i)
PPD_2_Date = Worksheets("Data").Range("BA" & i)

If PPD_1_Date > PPD_2_Date Then
 Worksheets("PPDCI").Range("A" & j & ":C" & j).Value = 
 Worksheets("Data").Range("F" & i & ":H" & i).Value
 Worksheets("PPDCI").Range("F" & j).Value = PPD_1_Date
j = j + 1
Else
 If PPD_1_Date < PPD_2_Date Then
  Worksheets("PPDCI").Range("A" & j & ":C" & j).Value = 
  Worksheets("Data").Range("F" & i & ":H" & i).Value
  Worksheets("PPDCI").Range("F" & j).Value = PPD_2_Date
  Worksheets("PPDCI").Range("G" & j).Value = "ELSE IF CONDITION"
  j = j + 1
 Else
'If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Data").Range(PPD_1_Date & i).Value) = True And 
 IsEmpty(Worksheets("Data").Range(PPD_2_Date & i).Value) = True Then
   'GoTo EmptyRange
'Else
  Worksheets("Error").Range("A" & k & ":C" & k).Value = 
  Worksheets("Data").Range("F" & i & ":H" & i).Value
  Worksheets("Error").Range("F" & j).Value = "REVIEW PPD DATA"
  k = k + 1
  'End If

 End If
End If
EmptyRange:

'k = k + 1

Next i

End Function
```

[image]

I would expect all the rows that qualify for the final Else statement to be grouped together and not missing any of the cells. Should I be incrementing k (k = k+1) somewhere else in the code? Any feedback is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Think I may have figured out my own problem, this code: Worksheets("Error").Range("F" & j).Value = "REVIEW PPD DATA", should be:  Worksheets("Error").Range("F" & **k**).Value = "REVIEW PPD DATA"

Comment: 1) Please don't post pictures of code. Insert code between code tags. 2) Please remember to post answers as answers not as comments so everyone can benefit. Posting as an answer is easier to find and easier to read. 3) Well done on solving!